# Showing that the sequence $\{(-1)^n \exp{in\pi/3}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has three accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis

I'm doing a proof which is quiet long, so I have divided the proof in subproofs. One of the subproofs are that I want to show that $\{(-1)^n \exp{in\pi/3}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has three accumulation points. I wanted to use the fact the the complex exponential function $e_k = \exp{ikx}$ is periodic with period $P = 2\pi / |k|$. But I do not think I can do that.

I also thought about just calculating the terms for $n=1,..,4$. But I do not thing that is elegant :-/.

I will appreciate some help!

Kind regards

Comment: I suggest swallowing your pride and doing some calculation.....

Comment: Thanks, this is want I wanted to hear. Is it ok to calculate the first four terms of sequence and write "notice that the sequence is accumulated around these three points: ...." ?

Comment: @MartinR That is not correct.

Comment: @Xenusi: My fault. With  $\omega = \exp(i 4 \pi/3)$  your sequence is $(\omega^n)$ and that has period 3.

Comment: How did you get $\exp (n i 4 \pi / 3) 
$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $-1 = e^{i \pi}$ we have
$$
 (-1)^n e^{i n \pi /3} = e^{i n \pi/ 3 + i n \pi} = e^{i 4 n \pi/ 3} = \omega^n
$$
with $\omega = \exp(i 4 \pi/3)$. Since $\omega^3 = 1$ the sequence is periodic with period 3 and has the three (distinct) accumulation points $1, \omega, \omega^2$.

Comment: Yes, I see. But have do you get the periode to be $3$ using the formular for the period  $P = 2\pi /|k| $?